# QFileDialog: no signals emitted, wrong starting directory

Tags: pyqt, signals-slots

I'm trying to show a `QFileDialog` using the following piece of code:

```py
import os, sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self._button = QPushButton('Test button')
        self._button.clicked.connect(self._onButtonClicked)

        self._layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self._layout.addWidget(self._button)
        self.setLayout(self._layout)

    def _onButtonClicked(self):
        self._dialog = QFileDialog(self, 'Select directory')
        self._dialog.setDirectory(os.getenv('HOME'))
        self._dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)
        self._dialog.directoryEntered.connect(self._onDirEntered)
        self._dialog.exec_()

    def _onDirEntered(self, directory):
        print("Entered directory: %s" % (directory))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Two problems here:

1. The `directoryEntered` signal is never emitted, at least I don't get any output from the script (except for some KDE warnings about Samba support, etc.); actually no signal from the `QFileDialog` class I tried to connect to gets emitted in the example. What am I doing wrong?
2. In this example I set the starting directory to `$HOME`, but the dialog will start in `/home` instead and have my home directory selected in the listing instead of starting directly in my home directory. Can I change this behaviour somehow?

I'm using Python 3.4.0 with PyQt 4.10.4-2.

Both problems **do not** occur when using a non-native dialog as suggested by @ekhumoro.

Comment: I can't reproduce any of the behaviour you report (using Linux, but not KDE). I'm a little surprised that you get KDE warnings, because using the `QFileDialog` constructor should give you a non-native dialog. What happens if you do `self._dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)`?

Comment: Ok, with a non-native dialog these problems do in fact not occur, I start in my home directory and get the events. Unfortunately, this doesn't really solve the problem for the native dialog.

Comment: On problem (2): it could be related to [this KDE bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229375). Try adding a trailing slash or non-existent filename to the start directory.

Comment: Neither a trailing slash nor a non-existent filename work.

Comment: Okay, but if you use an existing sub-directory (e.g. `$HOME/.config`), it will "work", right? I know this is not a solution - I'm just trying to confirm you are experiencing the same bug as noted above.

Comment: Yes, that directly puts me  in the home directory. But then again I got `.config` in the `Name` line edit as a preset. When using a visible file or directory it highlights those like in the initial problem.

Comment: As I said: it's not a real solution. I can't really see what can be done, I'm afraid. It just seems to be buggy on KDE. Personally, I always try to avoid using the native dialogs precisely because of this kind of issue (and the fact that the native dialogs are generally much slower than Qt's built-in ones).